# Javascript string-replace function ignoring hyphen

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following code:

```
ttt = 'hello---,,..there';
tt2 = strip(ttt);
alert(tt2);
            
function strip(str){
  return str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-_]/g, '');
}
```

The alert gives `hello,,..there`

I would expect it to give `hello---,,..there` as all the characters, including hyphens, are specified as exceptions in the replacement function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the hyphen:

```
'hello---,,..there'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,.\-_]/g, ''); // => "hello---,,..there"
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that was simple! Thanks! Not sure why the hyphen has to be escaped though?

Comment: In short the hyphen in a character class `[]` is meant to indicate a range for exampel `[a-z]`. That's why you have to escape it. See also here [Regexp Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)